# Item is out of stock but available on storefront

Tags: magento2, quantity, items

Can you please guys explain, me how can I do this ?

**"If an item is out of stock can it stay on the site but say `'More stock on its way'` and not allow people to order until stock is available again."**

Answer (score 1):

1.On admin page, Click on Stores, then under the Setting section, choose Configuration.

2.In this page, you find the Inventory section under Catalog. Expand the Stock Options section and you can start to set the custom status of the product.
[image]

3.You want to display the product out of stock, you set the Display Out of Stock Products section is Yes. In contrast, set No if you want to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the `Display Out of Stock Products` setting to `yes`
in `admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options`

And then you can override/modify `addtocart.phtml` in your module/theme to show to the required text.